# no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. while uploading image to s3 using aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('./config.json');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var configuration = require('./jwtconfig.js');
const isBase64 = require('is-base64');
const base64mime = require('base64mime');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-2' });
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
const bucket = "bucketname";
let path = "bucketpath/";

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: config.dbhost,
    user: config.dbuser,
    password: config.dbpassword,
    database: config.dbname
});
module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const { eventname, event_type, event_platform, event_date, co_host, stream_url, description, event_time, user_id, zoom_id,c_id } = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const image = JSON.parse(event.body).imageBase64;
    //let token = event.headers['x-access-token'] || event.headers['authorization'];
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    // if (token) {
    // jwt.verify(token, configuration.secret, (err, decoded) => {
    //          if (err) {
    //              callback({
    //                  statusCode: 201,
    //                  headers: {
    //                      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    //                      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,x-access-token",
    //                       //  "Access-Control-Request-Headers":"x-access-token",
    //                      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST"
    //                  },
    //                  body: JSON.stringify(err)
    //              }, null);
    //     } else {
    //             event.decoded = decoded;
    if (eventname && event_type && event_date) {
        let key = path + "img" + "_" + new Date().getTime();
        const options = {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: key,
            StorageClass: 'STANDARD_IA',
            ACL: 'public-read',
            ContentType: base64mime(image),
            ContentEncoding: 'base64',
            Body: Buffer.from(image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64')
        };
        s3.upload(options, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {

                callback({
                    "statusCode": 400,
                    "headers": {
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,x-access-token,Origin,XMLHttpRequest",
                         "Access-Control-Request-Headers":"x-access-token",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST",
                       "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : "true"
                    },
                    "body": JSON.stringify(err)
                }, null);
            } else {
                var bhu = data["Location"];
                callback(null, { statusCode: 200, headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" ,  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With,x-access-token, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, token, XMLHttpRequest"},body:JSON.stringify(bhu)});
                pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
                    if (err) {
                        return callback(err, null);
                    } 
                    var quer = `Insert INTO event (eventname,event_type,event_platform,event_date,co_host,stream_url,description,event_time,user_id,zoom_id,image,c_id) values ('${eventname}', '${event_type}', '${event_platform}', '${event_date}','${[co_host]}', '${stream_url}', '${description}','${event_time}','${event.pathParameters.user_id}','${zoom_id}','${bhu}','${c_id}')`;
                    connection.query(quer, [parseInt(event.pathParameters.user_id)], function (error, results, field) {
                        if (error) {
                            callback({
                                statusCode: 400,
                                headers: {
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,OPTIONS,UPDATE,DELETE",
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With,x-access-token, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, token, XMLHttpRequest",
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : "true"
                                },
                                body: JSON.stringify(error)
                            }, null);
                        } else {
                            var insertId = results.insertId;
                            var getquer = `SELECT * FROM event WHERE id = ${insertId}`;
                            connection.query(getquer, function (error, result) {
                                if (error) {
                                    callback({
                                        statusCode: 400,
                                        headers: {
                                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,OPTIONS,UPDATE,DELETE",
                                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With,x-access-token, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, token, XMLHttpRequest",
                                            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : "true"
                                        },
                                        body: JSON.stringify(error)
                                    }, null);
                                } else {
                                    var customRes = [];
                                    customRes = {
                                        "statusCode": 200,
                                        "message": "event created successfully",
                                        "data": result,
                                        //"token data":decoded
                                    };

                                    callback(null, {
                                        statusCode: 200,
                                        headers: {
                                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,OPTIONS,UPDATE,DELETE",
                                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With,x-access-token ,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, token, XMLHttpRequest",
                                            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : "true"
                                        },
                                        body: JSON.stringify(customRes)
                                    });
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    });

                });
            }

        });


    }
//    });

   // } else {
        // var customRes = {};
    //   customRes = {
    //          "statusCode": 201,

    //          "message": "token is not provided",
    //      };

    //      callback(null, {
    //          statusCode: 201,
    //          headers: {
    //              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    //                 "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,x-access-token",
    //              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST"
    //          },
    //         body: JSON.stringify(customRes)

        // });
    //}

};
```

I am getting  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error when accessing this code API in front end . i am using aws lambda function to upload image to s3 bucket . i have also included . access-control-allow -origin header in my code . i have enable proxy integration in API gateway . but I am getting this error

Comment: I guess it's better if you upload to s3 using presigned urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you've already open CORS in your NodeJS code but it's just for lambda part only. But all of request will be passed through API Gateway thus you may need to open CORS in AWS API Gateway.

Go to your API Gateway **Path** > then click **Actions** dropdown > Click **Enable CORS** as per attach for reference.

[image]

Comment: Can you show me your full error message? Sometimes server error are showing as CORS error at frontend console.

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://iccbgcg2.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/createevent/3. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).@PPShein this is the error which is i am getting in console

Comment: @PrateekPareek i am not sure whether you have already attached IAM role to lambda to give permission to upload to S3 or not. If not yet, assign `s3:upload` policy in IAM role. Or another one is you may configure `CORS configuration` in S3 bucket as well. Hope it woule help.

Comment: yes i already attached IAM role to give permission and also set cors configuration in s3 bucket as well

Comment: @PrateekPareek that's your code issue then. Because I found you're using `var pool = mysql.createPool({` connection but you didn't include `mysql` npm library in your code.

Comment: sorry I included MySQL library in my code. this was typing mistake. this API is working fine inn postman but showing error in frontend so issue is not in code I think